# PHP variable keeps returning 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to use ACF with Wordpress to insert this code into a specific area on my front page. Can anyone help me figure out why this function keeps returning 0?

```
function tjenestefunksjon() {
    $toReturn = ' ';
    if (have_rows('tjeneste')):
        $toReturn += '<ul class="tjenestelist">';
        while (have_rows('tjeneste')):
            the_row(); 
            // vars
            $ikon = get_sub_field('ikon');
            $tjenestenavn = get_sub_field('tjenestenavn');
            $tjenestebeskrivelse = get_sub_field('tjenesteinformasjon'); 
            $toReturn += '<li class="tjeneste">';
            $toReturn += '<i class="'. $ikon . '"></i>';
            $toReturn += '<p id="tjenestenavn">' . $tjenestenavn . '</p>';
            $toReturn += '<p id="tjenesteinformasjon">' . $tjenestebeskrivelse . '</p>';
            $toReturn += '</li>';
        endwhile;
        $toReturn += '</ul>';
    endif;
    return $toReturn;
}
```

Comment: use .= instead of += with your $toReturn Variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP uses the `.=` operator for concatenate, not `+=`.

`+=` Will use the Integer datatype and thus return a number, instead of the string.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, consider marking my Answer as solution, please.

Comment: Yes done, had to wait a few minutes until I could press it :)